# Posting to FB Application Activities Graph API endpoint with Flask

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, flask

I'm building a bot in FB Messenger and I want to log custom events to track them with FB Analytics. I'm new to Flask and it would be really helpful if someone could give me some orientation on how to structure de post request as stated in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/bots-for-messenger#logging-custom-events). For example I tried this (trying to replicate the example given in Node.js in the docs) and it's not working:

```
@app.route('/fb', methods=['POST'])
def custom_event():
    info = {
        'event': 'CUSTOM_APP_EVENTS',
        'custom_events': jsonify(**{'eventName': 'mateo'}),
        'advertiser_tracking_enabled': 0,
        'application_tracking_enabled': 0,
        'page_id': XXX,
    }
    r = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/XXX/activities', data = info)
    return r['success']
```

I'm receiving this error:

```
TypeError: 'Response' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
2017-01-29T00:22:54.394255+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
```

Thanks in advance! I'm driving crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it! It helped a lot printing the status code and text (as a newbie I didn't). I was missing that custom_events must be a list and other details explained by @Suever in his answers here.

```
import json
import requests

info = {
        'event': 'CUSTOM_APP_EVENTS',
        'custom_events': json.dumps([{'_eventName': 'mateo'}]),
        'advertiser_tracking_enabled': 0,
        'application_tracking_enabled': 0,
        'page_id': <page_id>,
        'extinfo': json.dumps(['mb1']),
        'page_scoped_user_id': recipientId,
    }
print(info)
r = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/<app_id>/activities', data = info)

print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

`requests.post` returns a [`Response`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response) object and *not* the response data itself. In order to access the JSON data returned by the service, you'll need to use the [`json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.json) method which will return a `dict` containing the JSON data.

```
r = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/XXX/activities', data = info)

return r.json()['success']
```

A better approach may be to actually check the status code of the `Response` object to make sure that it was a successful POST before trying to access the `status` field

```
if r.status_code == 201:
    return r.json()['success']
else:
    # Return the error information
    return r.text()
```

Additionally, based upon the documentation you are missing the following fields in your request

- `extinfo` (should be `json.dumps(['mb1'])`)
- `page_scoped_user_id`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, that was a problem but now I realize that I'm misunderstanding the documentation because the error it returns me is:
`KeyError: 'success'`

Comment: @Mateo Ok so the response isn't what you'd expect. You can print the output of `r.json()` to see what fields *are* in the response

Comment: @Mateo Based on the docs, there are two possible response structs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/activities/

Comment: Really thanks for the help. How do I choose which type of struct will come? Thanks again!!

Comment: @Mateo I'm not entirely sure, what happened when you printed out the JSON response? Was it the larger response?

Comment: I'm not structuring ok the request I think, because I'm receiving `ERROR in app: Exception on /fb [POST]` I'll return here and let you know when I figure it out :) Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134287/discussion-between-mateo-and-suever).