# Chatbot FB posting response with python and flask

Tags: python, facebook, flask, facebook-chatbot

I'm trying to run this [chatbot sample](https://github.com/vernwalrahul/my-messenger-bot/blob/master/app.py), however when I submit a sample update to my server, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in **call**
>       return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
>       response = self.handle_exception(e)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
>       reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
>       response = self.full_dispatch_request()
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
>       rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
>       reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)>
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
>       rv = self.dispatch_request()
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
>       return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint
>
> File "c:\echo.py", line 30, in webhook
>       for messaging_event in entry['messaging']:
>   KeyError: 'messaging'

I've tried something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916583/posting-to-fb-application-activities-graph-api-endpoint-with-flask), but don't work for me.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN = "XXX"

bot = Bot(PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def verify():
    # Webhook verification
    if request.args.get("hub.mode") == "subscribe" and 
request.args.get("hub.challenge"):
        print 'get ok'
        if not request.args.get("hub.verify_token") == "hello":
            return "Verification token mismatch", 403
        return request.args["hub.challenge"], 200
    return "Hello world", 200


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    data = request.get_json()
    log(data)

    if data['object'] == 'page':
        for entry in data['entry']:
            for messaging_event in entry['messaging']:

                # IDs
                sender_id = messaging_event['sender']['id']
                recipient_id = messaging_event['recipient']['id']

                if messaging_event.get('message'):
                    # Extracting text message
                    if 'text' in messaging_event['message']:
                        messaging_text = messaging_event['message']['text']
                    else:
                        messaging_text = 'no text'

                    # Echo
                    response = messaging_text
                    bot.send_text_message(sender_id, response)

    return "ok", 200


def log(message):
    print(message)
    sys.stdout.flush()


 if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True, port = 80)
```

Comment: Sounds like there simply is no `entry['messaging']` …

Comment: @CBroe I send this `{
  "field": "messages",
  "value": {
    "page_id": "1067280970047460"
  }
}`

Comment: Not about what you send (at least not primarily) - the data received by your webhook does not contain what you think it does, that’s what’s causing the error. So step one would be that you log that data structure somewhere, so that you can check what it actually contains.

Comment: @CBroe as the facebook example, the field messaging is anyway

Comment: You already have `log(data)` in there, so presumably this goes to some log file or similar? Then go check there what it _actually_ contained.

Comment: @CBroe contains the error I presented above

Comment: That is the only the traceback _after_ the error occurred. I wanted you to check what `log(data)` has logged - that is the actual data you want to loop over after all. So, where is the output of _that_ log call?

Comment: `{u'entry': [{u'changes': [{u'field': u'messages', u'value': {u'page_id': u'1067280970047460'}}], u'id': u'0', u'time': 1531747485}], u'object': u'page'}`, thats the data. I don't save the log

Comment: And now where exactly in that do you see the key `messaging`, which your code tries to access …?